# How can i activate wiki tab in openkm dashboard?

Tags: wiki, openkm

I investigate on openkm 6.3 abilities and learn about running them but there is not any guide about activating wiki tab in dashboard on its wiki pages or forum, note that my openkm is not professional version and it uses community version.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I regret to inform that the community version of OpenKM not have the wiki tab. This functionality corresponds to the cloud version and the professional version. If you need help, please contact us via http://forum.openkm.com

Thanks

Fuensanta Martínez